# swift: didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have tableViewController. I want to click on 1 cell and get `print("0")` and click on 2 cell and get `print("1")`

But my code doesn’t work. Why?

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10 
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(format: "Cell%d", indexPath.row), for: indexPath)
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        print("0")
    }

    else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        print("1")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: self)
    }

}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" does not explain much. What is happening?

Comment: probably you didn't set delegate and datasource for this tableview.

Comment: What version of Swift are you using?

Comment: Update question

Comment: @vadian swift 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 3 the signature of the method in an `UITableViewController` is

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Comment: Thank you. If I use `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: «detailSegue», sender: self)` in each `line` in this case `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) ` not need to use?

Comment: `prepare(for segue` is always needed if you have to pass data to the destination controller. In your case I recommend to connect the segue to the **cell** (rather than to the controller), then `didSelectRowAt` is not needed and the cell is passed through the `sender` parameter of `prepare(for`.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you are trying to mix between Swift 3 and older version. Please change it to:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```