# UITableViewController's didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using an `UITableViewController` for it and I override the following method and try to enable different segues when the user select different row.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("You selected row #\(indexPath.row)!")
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 3:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue3", sender: self)
    case 8:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue8", sender: self)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

But actually, this method never get called, and the print out never show up when I select a row.

I did enable single selection, enable user interaction and set the delegate and datasource to the controller itself (That's automatically set when using `UITableViewController`, right?)

I am using static cells and default `UITableViewCell`. The view controller is `UITableViewController`.

[image]

**Update**:

I try to replace:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath)
```

With:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

And this doesn't work also.

Comment: Have you set the delegate?

Comment: What version of Xcode are using? While you say you are using a `UITableViewController`, you need to override the default implementation, which means you need the keyword `override` for the method. Your _Update_ is not clear enough whether you put `override` or not.

Comment: Check the delegate is connected with the viewController

Comment: @OOPer Yes I should override that method.

Comment: Based on the answer you accepted, you are using Swift 2. You really should not be using that any more. You need to upgrade to Swift 3 since Swift 4 is now in beta.

Comment: @rmaddy I already update the answer's choice. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: Now I'm really confused. After I initially marked your question as a duplicate, you updated your question stating that you tried using the updated `didSelectRowAt` method but it also didn't work. But now you choose that answer as the correct one. What's different between what you tried and what is posted in the answer?

Comment: @rmaddy I am using UITableViewController but that post is using UIViewController. The only difference is that I realized that I should override that function under UITableViewController. Without the override, it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749136/swift-didselectrowatindexpath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for Swift 3

```
override  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    // your code ...  
}
```

and one thing make sure your tableView `single selection` property is selected ...

Comment: The question clearly states they are using `UITableViewController`. You do not need to set the delegate or dataSource with `UITableViewController`.

Answer (score 4):

Also check the selection of tableView in AttributeInspector of table view in your Storyboard. It should be selected to single selection.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a `UITableViewController` `override` the function. Otherwise if you are using a tableView in a `ViewController` make sure the `delegate` is set to your `ViewController` class.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("You selected row #\(indexPath.row)!")
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 3:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue3", sender: self)
        case 8:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue8", sender: self)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I should override that method. The tutorial I read is about UIViewController and I don't know the difference before.

Answer (score 0):

Ok from what I’m seeing with your code. You is trying to print a string  and also segue at the same time. But which object is you selecting to segue. It should  be an array or something else example:

```
Var array[“Swift”, “IOS”]


DidSelect{

Switch: array[indexpath.row]
Case 3:
            Print(“ u selected /(indexpath.row)”)
     PerformSegue.........
Case 4 and so on.....
```